# File opening after upload

Tags: 2010

I am uploading files to a document library. After every upload the document is opened up on my computer. Can I change this Behavior? I have been so far unable to find a setting for this behavior.

Comment: It appears to be only when I am linking to the upload form from another page and not when it uses the popover upload form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

adding a source attribute to the link did the trick

Comment: Hi Eric, could you please elaborate a bit more on this solution or give an example?

Comment: ok no worries, I have found it:

<a onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" href="/etc.

This will add the "Source=" url query string parameter to the address, which will load the initial page after the upload.

Comment: All I did was edit the links in sharepoint designer and added a source parameter to the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric for your solution, I had a similar issue and have now resolved it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't quite clear, but...

If what you are asking is why some documents open in the browser when a user clicks the file, and you would rather have them DOWNLOAD the file, then the answer is that SharePoint maintains a list of MIME types that it considers safe and tells IE to open, using an HTTP header that is passed to the browser (X-Download-Options)

You may also have the web application browser file handling style set to *permissive*, rather than *strict*. **Having this set to *permissive* is risky business**, so it's best to make sure it is set to strict, and simply add/remove MIME types as you like.

**Removing a MIME file type is a simple matter of hitting the powershell and running the following command:** *$webApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove()*

[This blog post](http://www.pdfshareforms.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/) is a good reference for more information on the topic.

Comment: No, When I upload a file to my document library, its automatically opening the document once you submit the additional properties. When Ideally i just want it to go either to the default page or to the document library. I also noticed that its not happening when I upload through the Add Document link at the bottom of the document library web view. It's only happening when i try to upload when I linked directly to that document libraries upload page.